# Python: passing value to input() automatically in a called script file

Tags: python

I am currently trying to help some friends who are taking an intro python course by creating a program that will run their programs by inputting values and comparing the output to an expected output.

As this is their first ever program, it only uses a main() function, meaning that their variables are defined by input statements that are inside of the main function that I need to call. So if their program looks like

```
def main():
     x = input('Enter something')
     print(x)
```

I want to be able to do something like

```
their_file.x = 'Hello World'
```

and have it pass 'Hello World' directly into x without it actually prompting an input command to the console. This is, obviously, so I can create a list of inputs and have my program elegantly iterate my loop thru their program and compare the outputs.

Bonus question:
Is there a way for me to pass the value of their print statements into a variable in my program without the print statements actually being printed into the console?

Kind regards

Comment: `x = 'Hello World`. If you don't want to prompt user for input, then don't use `input()`.

Comment: @David He doesn't want to change their programs, just automate running them.

Comment: If i understand correctly, you want to read an input from another program into your program. This is something like client server program. Have a look at socket programming by python.  Your friends program is client and your program is server, and server always tries to listen from clients for any inputs.

Comment: @RohithRangaraju That will require changing the programs to use sockets. A simpler solution is to use `Expect`.

Comment: @Barmar how would I use expect? Sorry I am only about a year and a bit into programming myself. I have heard about it but I have never actually learned what it does.

Comment: See https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/